# Use apply-template for each variable node-set XLST 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I have this **input**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Native xmlns="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Native/2011/11" version="2.0">
                <Header>
                    <OwnerCode>VISSHIMEL</OwnerCode>
                </Header>
        </Native>
```

And I have a declared node-set in my xslt:

```xml
<xsl:variable name="SupplierSCAC">
           <m>Yellow</m>
           <m>Red</m>
           <m>Green</m>
         </xsl:variable>
```

I'm trying to do a for each for this node set and select OwnerCode value "VISSHIMEL" but for some reason my template call is not getting the value. **Expected output is**:

```xml
<TariffCollection>
Yellow
<test>VISSHIMEL</test>
</TariffCollection>
<TariffCollection>
Red
<test>VISSHIMEL</test>
</TariffCollection>
<TariffCollection>
Green
<test>VISSHIMEL</test>
</TariffCollection>**
```

However, `<test>` is always empty. Here is my code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 s1 exsl" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Native/2011/11" xmlns:s1="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Universal/2011/11" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="SupplierSCAC">
           <m>Yellow</m>
           <m>Red</m>
           <m>Green</m>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($SupplierSCAC)/m">
            <xsl:call-template name="Test">
                <xsl:with-param name="SupplierSCAC" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
            <!-- <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Native" > -->
                <!-- <xsl:with-param name="SupplierSCAC" select="."/> -->
            <!-- </xsl:apply-templates> -->
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:template>
        
    <xsl:template name="Test" match="/s0:Native">
    <xsl:param name="SupplierSCAC"/>
        <TariffCollection>
            <xsl:value-of select="$SupplierSCAC"/>
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode"/>
            </test>
        </TariffCollection>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I know the for-each and the parameter is successfully displayed in the output but I don't know why I can't access the value of the xpath OwnerCode. I tried using apply-template instead but it's worse because I have no output at all. Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a template is invoked by an `xsl:call-template` instruction, the `match` attribute is ignored. Therefore, you are still in the context established by:

```
<xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($SupplierSCAC)/m">
```

and your instruction

```
<xsl:value-of select="s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode"/>
```

selects nothing because these nodes are in another document.

Try something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:s0="http://www.cargowise.com/Schemas/Native/2011/11" 
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" 
exclude-result-prefixes="s0 exsl" >
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
    
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="SupplierSCAC">
        <m>Yellow</m>
        <m>Red</m>
        <m>Green</m>
    </xsl:variable> 
    <xsl:variable name="root" select="/s0:Native" />
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($SupplierSCAC)/m">
        <TariffCollection>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <test>
                <xsl:value-of select="$root/s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode"/>
            </test>
        </TariffCollection>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
        
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that the result is an *XML fragment*, having no single root element.

Comment: Ok. It worked! I passed the variable root as an additional parameter on the call-template. I can't understand why directly calling the root node doesn't work:

`<xsl:template name="Native">
  <xsl:param name="SupplierSCAC"/>
  <xsl:param name="root"/>
   <TariffCollection>
    <xsl:value-of select="$SupplierSCAC"/>
    <test>
     <xsl:value-of select="$root/s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode"/> <!--working-->
     <xsl:value-of select="/s0:Native/s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode"/> <!--not working-->
    </test>
   </TariffCollection>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: As I said, when you are in the context of `exsl:node-set($SupplierSCAC)` the expression `/s0:Native/s0:Header/s0:OwnerCode` selects nothing because the variable is a document of its own. -- P.S. I don't see why you need the named template at all.